# Power Bi embedded - Dynamic Filter on report

Tags: powerbi-embedded

```
'const filter = {
$schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
target: {
    table: "Geo",
    column: "Region"
    },
operator: "In",
values: ["West"]
};'
```

Is there any option/function/api to get Fields  (table names and columns) used in a Power BI report?

Basically, I want to apply dynamic filters on reports in Power BI embedded, where I need to pass the table name and column name in filter object. Kindly help.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such API (yet). [Get Tables In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_gettablesingroup) works only with Push datasets, and I have doubts it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Power BI report authoring library.
Follow the given steps to filter the visuals by the Fields (table name and column name):

1. Create an authoring page
2. Set the authoring page as active
3. Create a visual on the authoring page with required data fields
4. Get the data fields of the visual using `.getDataFields()`
   ex- `dataFields` = visual.getDataFields('Data_Field_Name').

   [image]
5. Create a filter and add the table name and column name from dataFields
6. Use `updateFilters` to update the filter the visual

You can try the above steps in Power BI Playground:
https://playground.powerbi.com/dev-sandbox (Go to Authoring section in the Playground first)

Please find the references below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-add-visual#how-to-create-a-visual-and-bind-it-to-data
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/data-fields#get-data-fields
https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-report-authoring